# Saving different object types as part the same RDD in cassandra in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm parallelising a list of queries in spark and my RDD is mapped into a collection of objects where the object type would be different based on the data source attribute of each Query. I'm having a map of String -> function where each function gives me the collection of objects to be saved into cassandra. For instance:

```
val processingMethods: Map[String, (String) => Seq[Any]] = Map("trends" -> processTrendsResponse, "yahoo" -> processYahooResponse)
```

where processTrendsResponse is defined as a function which returns Seq[Trends]  and processYahooResponse returns Seq[Yahoo] where Trends and Yahoo defined are defined as case classes:

```
case class Trends(entity: String, time : Long, value: Long)
case class Yahoo(entity: String, time: Long, value: Long)
```

To accomodate both Trends and Yahoo types, processingMethods Map was defined as Map[String, (String) => Seq[Any]]. But when I perform the saveToCassandra action in spark, I'm gated with  an exception -

```
scala.ScalaReflectionException: <none> is not a term
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any is always a bad idea. Try an ADT.

Comment: I've tried using a trait - Schema and had made Trends and Yahoo case classes extend it and had tried using Schema type instead of any with the same result.

Comment: I'd say use an extra field then. Call it "type". If you want, write your own serialization/deserialization or just use a common object.

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate?

Comment: `case class Column(entity: String, time: Long, value: Long, type: String)` and `type` is either `"trends"` or `"yahoo"`.